# Control a Mathematica kernel from the front-end and from python

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, external-calls, python

I'd like to be able to start and control a Mathematica kernel/front-end from python and be able to evaluate things in a notebook and query results on the python side too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

For this I'll make use of a little thing I recently wrote to answer a much deeper question: [Control Front End in "mathlink" mode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98686/control-front-end-in-mathlink-mode)

The heart of this will be a little package to make a kernel that both looks for stuff on stdin and from its notebook interface. That package lives [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/SubprocessKernel.wl). We can load it simply by running:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/SubprocessKernel.wl"];
SubprocessKernel`OpenSubprocessNotebook[]
```

There's much more we can do with this, but for now and for proof-of-principle this will suffice.

Once we have that package everything we need to do is really on the python side, writing a little script that starts a kernel in a subprocess (I use pexpect since it makes life much nicer), links it to a front-end, and creates a shell that can play with this kernel. Here's my quick implementation of that:

```python
import pexpect, re, time

### Just for the shell
import tkinter as tk
from GUITools import InterpreterText as shell

### Create a Mathematica instance bound to a controlled kernel

wolfker="/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel"
proc=pexpect.spawn(wolfker)
script='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/SubprocessKernel.wl'
cmd='Get["{}"]; SubprocessKernel`OpenSubprocessNotebook[];'.format(script)
proc.sendline(cmd)
proc.expect('Starting kernel\.\.\.')

### Convenience function for getting junk out of Mathematica

def call_mathematica(cmd):
    proc.expect(".*")
    proc.sendline(cmd)
    proc.expect(r"(>> ------ Output: \d+ ------ >>)|(Out\[)")
    leader=proc.after.decode()
    if leader.startswith('>> ------ Output:'):
        proc.expect('<< ------ Output: \d+ ------ <<')
        leader=leader+proc.before.decode()+proc.after.decode()
    proc.expect(".+")
    res=leader+proc.after.decode()
    chunks=re.findall(r'>> ------ Output: \d+ ------ >>.*?<< ------ Output: \d+ ------ <<', res, re.DOTALL)

    if len(chunks)==0:
        chunks=res
    else:
        chunks=["\n".join(chunk.splitlines()[1:-2]) for chunk in chunks]

    if len(chunks)==1:
        chunks=chunks[0]

    return chunks

### Create a little shell to interact with the made Mathematica instance

mathshell=shell(variables={'Mathematica':proc, 'call_mathematica':call_mathematica});
mathshell.pack(expand=True, fill='both');
mathshell.mainloop()
```

If you're going to actually use this you can also change the initialization under `cmd` so that you set the `$SubprocessREPLSettings` to things that will treat you better (in particular you can change the function that writes results to stdout so that they're in, say, JSON so that python can read them directly).

You could even potentially make use of the stuff I have [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-PyTools/tree/master/Resources/MLib) and [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-PyTools/tree/master/Packages/MLib) that attempts to provide an interface for that kind of thing. In particular one could use this as part of a bidirectional interface to allow convenient control of Mathematica from python with some level of native type conversion.

For now, here's a screenshot showing that it does indeed work:

[image]

The python terminal is in the lower right and you can see that I was able to access variables defined in the Mathematica notebook in the python terminal.

There's much more we could do (and maybe should) but that's for another day...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a much better answer that uses native data exchange, more convenient syntax, and a slew of other improvements. We'll use the [PJLink](https://github.com/b3m2a1/PJLink) package I've been working on recently. I wrote about it [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/pjlink-hooking-up-mathematica-and-python.html#main-content). There's a nice demo there that I'll discuss again here.

First I load up python in whatever way I want (I chose Jupyter there). Then I start one of these `SubprocessKernels` as in my other answer. This time it'll connect via MathLink, though.

```python
import os, sys
pjlink_path = "~/Documents/Python/IDEA/PJLink" #this path will change
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser(pjlink_path))

from SubprocessKernel import SubprocessKernel
from SubprocessKernel import MathematicaBlock, LinkEnvironment

ker = SubprocessKernel()
def MEval(expr, wait = True, kernel = ker):
  kernel.drain()
  return kernel.evaluate (expr, wait = wait)
ker.start()
ker.start_evaluator()

with MathematicaBlock():
  res = MEval(Set (M.hi, "Hello from python!"))

res

#Out:
'Hello from python!'
```

And as discussed in that linked post, we can also call into python from the notebook that `ker.start()` opened.

Here's the final screenshot I had from my demo there (sorry about the bad resolution):

[image]

We see there that we've gotten bidirectional control and even got a plot that was made in Mathematica to show up in a Jupyer notebook (Mathematica-inspired front-end for python).